# How to get value of form submission popup.html chrome extension

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to get the value of user input in a form to pass to a javascript function in a chrome extension. The issue is I don't know how to get the user input.

This is part of my manifest.json file:

```
,"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "./assets/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"

},
```

popup.html i.e the form I want to submit:

```
...
<script src = "popup.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <p>Enter here</p>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <form id = "form" >
        <input id = "shows"> </input>
        <input type = "submit" id = "submitButton">
    </form>

</div>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

I know I can't do inline javascript in chrome extension so I am using addEventListener to listen for a form submission. It is currently calling the function handleClick() but I need to pass in the value of the input, and I'm not sure what to put as the parameter. here is my popup.js file:

```
$(function() {
console.log("console logging works");


document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", handleClick());


function handleClick(val) {
    console.log("calling handleClick"); //printing
    console.log(val); //prints undefined

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        from: "popup",
        subject: val
    });
}
```

});

I also tried this which didn't work either:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", handleClick(), false);


function handleClick() {

    var show = form.elements[0].value;
    console.log(show); //prints blank
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        from: "popup",
        subject: show
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do:
`.addEventListener("submit", handleClick(), false)`
by putting parentheses after `handleClick` you are calling the function and passing its result to `addEventListener` (which in this case is `undefined` since your function has no `return` statement).

What you want to do is directly pass the function to `addEventListener`, which will then take care of calling it with an `event` object for you (this is called a `callback`):
`.addEventListener("submit", handleClick, false)`

Comment: I tried this but what's strange is it doesn't seem to call the function anymore, I added a console.log statement in handleClick() and nothing is printed when I do it the way you are saying

Comment: That means the `submit` event isn't fired for some reason. Double-check that the elements you're attaching the listeners to really exists `document.getElementById("form")`, and that it has a `<input type="submit">`