# Form Submission within a Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build my first Chrome Extension.  I need it to have a simple form that submits.  I'm having trouble getting anything to run on my popup.js file. I found this post to be similar but can't seem to get even the basic logging to work in the console. [How to get value of form submission popup.html chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485698/how-to-get-value-of-form-submission-popup-html-chrome-extension)

Here is my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<form id="useCasePostForm">
<input type="text" id="useCase" /> 
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my current try at the popup.js

```
$(function() {
console.log("console logging works");


document.getElementById("useCasePostForm").addEventListener("submit", handleClick, false);


function handleClick(val) {
    console.log("calling handleClick"); //printing
    console.log(val); //prints undefined

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        from: "popup",
        subject: val
    });
}
});
```

My other attempt I came up with this which I think I was getting a bit ahead of myself on:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {

     // Handle the bookmark form submit event with our useCasePost function
     document.getElementById('useCasePostForm')
             .addEventListener('submit', useCasePostFunc);

 });
 function useCasePostFunc(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    conosle.log("in the function")
    var useCase = document.getElementById("useCase")
     //The URL to POST our data to
     var postUrl = 'https://localhost:8080/useCases/create';
     console.log("in function")
     // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
     $.ajax({
        'url': postUrl,
        "type": "POST",
        data:{
            id:4
        }
     })

 }
```

Here is my manifest file as well.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "PIT",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
   "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "https://app.hubspot.com/*"
    ],
    "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "content.js"]
  }
],
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

If anyone has any pointers on how I can receive the form submission as a first step it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on this, this ended up being the winning code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("the doc loaded")
    var form = document.getElementById("useCasePostForm")
    console.log(form)
    form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("added to the form")
    })
});
```